# Different marker for each location in Google Maps JavaScript API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Noob here, trying to do something simple-yet-complicated. On [this page](http://pollbludger.0catch.com/examples/frankstontest.htm) I have succeeded in placing a red 52 of a certain size where I want it. I have done this by making my own changes to a no doubt familiar-looking code sample from the Google Developers site:

```
  function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-38.153470, 145.141425)
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                                mapOptions);
  var image = 'http://pollbludger.0catch.com/numbers/alp-52-07.png';
  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-38.148594, 145.126124);
  var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map,
      icon: image
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

What I want to do now is add nine other markers at different points on the map, each different in some way from all the others. Like my red 52, each marker I propose to use has its own PNG stored at pollbludger.0catch.com. Can I just do this by coding each marker sequentially, rather than have it go through a loop?

Answer (score 0):

You need use the property "icon" with "url" property and change the new coordinates in "position". use icons with the size of 32x32.

If you do not know how to get the positions use this example and copy the values lat,lng

```
 var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map,
      icon : {
            url: 'img/yourimageurl.png',//full path of your image
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(30,40)//this control the size of your icon
        }  
  });
```

Comment: Thanks - that's helped point me in the right direction. I've resolved the issue now.